# Add an additional column to just a subfolder view (not for all library views)

Tags: document-library, column

I would like to add an extra column to one of the subfolder views I'm working with.

Basically, I have a large document library with 10 or so top-level folders. A few layers down, I would like to be able to have an extra column in one of the views, but I don't want that same column to appear throughout all the different levels of the folder hierarchy, because it will not be applicable to all those other locations.

Thanks!